# Compare unequal lists of strings in python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have two dataframes right now with Names in it, MDF and DF. I want to search DF for the names in MDF and fill in the row next to MDF with yes or no depending on if it is in DF. I am struggling particularly with the search function.

```
for index, row in mdf.iterrows():
  if df["First Name"].str.find(row['First Name']) == 0:
    print('true')
df[]
```

but I get an error that states

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or 
a.all().
```

What am i doing wrong? I also know that iterrows is not encouraged, but I am not sure how else to go about it?

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please [edit] and add the tag for it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand what you want to do. Please make a [mre] including example input data and desired output. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341) (same advice will probably apply even if you're using a different dataframe library).

Answer (score -1):

Your if statement returns a series of Boolean's rather than a single one. I believe you want to do `if df["First Name"].str.find(row['First Name']) == -1:` to see if your output Series is empty.

Alternatively, try `row['First Name'] in df['First Name'].values`

Comment: Why would it be empty? [`pandas.Series.str.find()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.find.html) puts `-1` if the substring is not present, it doesn't omit the value.

Comment: @wjandrea You're right, edited that.

Comment: Wait what? `len()` will never return a number less than 0.